# How can I find the first textbox in a container using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript to find the first textbox in a container, so I can set it to focused, but the textbox could be nested. Is there an easy way I can cycle through until I come across the first textbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].focus();`

Comment: Is this recursive? So if my container contains a bunch of nested items and the textbox is right at the top of the tree, will it work?

Comment: The [0] ensures it's the first child element with that tag. If you wish to search through elements: var inputs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i in inputs){ if(inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text'){ /*inputs[i] is the first input */ /*do something*/ break; /* break so you wont hit more than one input*/ } }